# using "git clone "http://xxxx" to download one repository, encounter the error：remote: Unauthorized fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://xxxx'

Tags: git, gerrit

we have built one gerrit server.

using "git clone "ssh://xxxx", i can clone the git repository from the server.

but change to use "git clone "http://xxxx", there is the following error:

`remote: Unauthorized`

`fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://xxxx'`

i promise i have the right permission(because i am an administrator) and password is correct.

how do i resolve this issue? will i need to set some gerrit server configuration?

Comment: Log on to the server and examine the server-side logs to see why it's rejecting your attempt to log in via http. (At a guess, perhaps it requires https instead.)

Comment: https instead of http?

Answer (score 0):

thanks torek, you remind me to check the server-side logs:

`WARN  com.google.gerrit.httpd.ProjectBasicAuthFilter : Authentication from xx.xx.xx.xx failed for xxx: Incorrect username or password`

i solved this issue. At first, i just want to try this idea, but it really solved the problem. i share this method for you. But it's queer, what theory it is?

solution:

`git clone "http://xxxx"`

`Password for 'http://xxxx':`

Now, you input the password which you login gerrit web, not 'HTTP Credentials'